# How to replace commas & any character with commas & space & that character using regular expression in Find & Replace in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

In a google spreadsheet there are many cells in a column which has data such as :

**Apple, Orange,Grapes, Berry**

I want it to be changed to :

**Apple, Orange, Grapes, Berry**

A simple find replace will replace all the commas in all the places. I only want space to be there where it is legitimately required as exampled above.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In the case without using regex, how about this? ``=JOIN(", ", ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(A1, ","))))`` "A1" has ``Apple, Orange,Grapes, Berry``.

Comment: Thanks for the formula @Tanaike. Your formula did do the task. However, i wanted to achieve it through Find & Replace box due to some reason.

Comment: No problem. But I'm glad your issue was solved.

Comment: Why this question is downvoted? Please let me know and I will amend any changes required @downvoter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `REGEXREPLACE`

to match a comma followed by non space character (capturing it)

```
,(\S)
```

to be replaced by using backreference `$1`

```
, $1
```

for example

```
REGEXREPLACE("a,b,c";",(\S)";", $1")
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. Thank you so much, @Nahuel

Comment: I don't know who and why this answer is downvoted. I have upvoted and accepted this as the accepted answer.